# Is it possible to embed an external program in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, embed

I'm currently developing a JavaFX desktop application that will take the place of an existing browser based application. 
This new application have the option of launching external applications made in swing. 
 
I'm now wondering if there's any chance of launching these external applications inside the existing JavaFX application?

In other words, is there a way to embed external applications in JavaFX?

Comment: If the external applications are Swing applications, you can include their main content in a [`SwingNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html). This assumes the applications are written in such a way that the main content is suitably factored out that it can be included in an arbitrary container, and not just in a `JFrame`.

Comment: @James_D The applications could be integrated that way, but they're quite big stand alone applications so integrating them in that way will take a bit too much work and effort. I have already integrated some minor legacy pieces with swing nodes but that is not doable in the long run.

Comment: You can't show a `JFrame` (or other window) *inside* a JavaFX application, if that's what you're asking. You can, of course, just make the window show on the desktop (providing the awt toolkit is present, and you thread things correctly).

Comment: @James_D That's exactly what I'm asking. I suspected as much when I didn't find any good answers while googling.
Atm we are just launching it as an external program and I think we have to stay content with that

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

JavaFX:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button fxButton = new Button("javafx button");
        fxButton.setOnAction(event -> new SwingTest());
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxButton, 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Swing:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import java.awt.Button;

public class SwingTest extends JFrame {

    SwingTest() {
        Button swingButton = new Button("swing button");
        getContentPane().add(swingButton);
        setSize(600, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }


}
```